# Check the values of an dynamic object properties

Tags: powershell, object

I have created an object as part of a customer import. Now each customer object has a dynamic set of properties that  all with have the prefix: "Cust." . I just need to loop through these properties and first get the name of the property and secondly, get the value.

```
$customerOptions = $Customer | Select-Object -property "Cust.*"
```

Comment: What does the code you included do?  Does it produce the correct properties and values?

Comment: You need to show how the objects inside `$Customer` are created and how you are going to use the output. Samples need to be simple and reproducable and the desired result should be clear.

Comment: @MikeShepard $Customer displays correctly Cust.Option1 = "Yes", Cust.Option2 = "No" etc. I just don't know how many Options there are or their values until runtime.

Comment: @FrodeF.  I used a simple  Import-CSV to initially populate my $Customer object then I filter again to get the properties I need for helper function.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's not much info about what `$Customer` is and what you want to use, I'll be guessing that `$Customer` is a single object and not an array. To loop through the properties starting with `Cust.` while being able to access both property-name and property-value, I would use this. Customize it to your needs:

```
$Customer = [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Object1"; "Cust.ID" = 1; "Cust.Car" = "Mercedes"}

$Customer.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'Cust.*' } | ForEach-Object {
    #Foreach property with a Cust. prefix
    $PropertyName = $_.Name
    $PropertyValue = $_.Value

    Write-Host "$PropertyName = '$PropertyValue'"
}
```

Output:

```
Cust.ID = '1'
Cust.Car = 'Mercedes'
```

If you are outputting an array and you only get a few properties (those available in the first object) like:

```
$Customer = @()
$Customer += [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Object1"; "Cust.ID" = 1; "Cust.Car" = "Mercedes"}
$Customer += [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Object2"; "Cust.ID" = 2; "Cust.Moped" = "Vespa"}

$Customer | Select-Object -Property "Cust.*"

Cust.ID Cust.Car
------- --------
      1 Mercedes
      2
```

Then you would want to create a full list of `cust.*`-properties and use that in your `Select-Object`-statement:

```
$AllCustProperties = $Customer | ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Properties } | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'Cust.*' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique

$Customer | Select-Object -Property $AllCustProperties

Cust.ID Cust.Car Cust.Moped
------- -------- ----------
      1 Mercedes           
      2          Vespa
```

Comment: Will try this as well - I am glad I asked as I would have taken a while to figure this out ;-(

Comment: F  $allCustProperties =  $User | ForEach-Object { $_.psObject.Properties } | Where-Object  { $_.Name -like 'CUST.*' }  . works like a charm. Thereafter, I use inspect each $custProperty.Value and $custProperty.Name in my foreach loop. I realised a had few bugs to fix prior to the suggested lines of code ;-(

Comment: I'm not sure what happend here. Was there a question somewhere in the comment? Did the answer solve your problem? :-)

Comment: Yes your suggestion solved my issue. The comment gave further details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the property names of each custom object through the hidden `psobject` property:

```
$Customer[0].psobject.Properties |Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Cust.*'} |Select Name,Value
```

You can also use this technique to enumerate all possible property names and feed those to `Select-Object`

```
$CustPropNames = $Customer |ForEach-Object {
    $_.psobject.Properties |Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Cust.*'} |Select-Object -Expand Name
} |Select-Object -Unique

$customerOptions = $Customer |Select-Object -Property $CustPropNames
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this