# creating dynamics properties to upload

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell

I have been using this code to upload a csv into azure tables.

I would like to make this more dynamic so it works for a number of different csv's.

How can I make the property's dynamic so i don't need to create new code for each csv.

```
foreach ($sub in $cmdata) {
Add-StorageTableRow -table $table -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey ([guid]::NewGuid().tostring()) -property @{
  "AT_Client" = $sub.AT_Client
  "MSFT_Client" = $sub.MSFT_Client
  "OrgID" = $sub.OrgID
  "QTY" = $Sub.QTY
  "Status" = $Sub.Status
  "BillingTerm" = $sub.BillingTerm
  "TermEndDate" = $sub.TermEndDate
  "OfferID" = $sub.OfferID
  "SubscriptionName"= $sub.SubscriptionName
  "Price" = $sub.Price
  "Opportunity_Number" = $sub.Opportunity_Number
  "PO" = $sub.PO
  "Account_Number" = $sub.Account_Number
  "CE" = $sub.ce
  "CE_Email" = $sub.CE_Email
} | Out-Null
```

Comment: You can use ````$sub.PSObject.Properties``` to get a collection of properties defined on the object, and then use the ```Name``` and ```Value``` of each to dynamically build a hashtable you can pass into ```Add-StorageTableRow``` as the ```-Property```. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160537/3156906

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create `DynamicTableEntity` object and adds properties to it dynamically based on the properties of the CSV file you can make use of below script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\XXXXXX\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\khan.csv"
$tableName = "<TableName>"
$partitionKey = "<key>"

# Get a reference to the storage account and table
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<yourResourceGroupName>" -Name "<yourStorageAccountName>"
$table = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context

# Loop through the CSV and add each row to the table
foreach ($sub in $csv) {
    $properties = $sub | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    $propertyValues = @{}
    foreach ($property in $properties) {
        $propertyValues[$property] = $sub.$property
    }

    # Create a DynamicTableEntity
    $row = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, ([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())

    # Add properties to the entity
    foreach ($property in $propertyValues.Keys) {
        $row.Properties.Add($property, $propertyValues[$property])
    }

    # Execute InsertOrReplace operation
    $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrReplace($row))
}
```

***Output***:

```
Result         : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity
HttpStatusCode : 204
Etag           : W/"datetime'2023-12-18T11%3A46%3A06.545XXX'"
SessionToken   : 
RequestCharge  : 
ActivityId     : 

Result         : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity
HttpStatusCode : 204
Etag           : W/"datetime'2023-12-18T11%3A46%3A07.0896XXXX'"
SessionToken   : 
RequestCharge  : 
ActivityId
```

[image]

Now when I check in storage account, Table are updated like below:

[image]

CSV file:

[image]

Make sure to assign `storage account contributor` and `Storage Table Data Contributor`

Comment: Thank you so much!  Why do you use the cosmos table operation instead add-storagetablerow.   I just wonder why one over the other.